# Python - How to use os.getenv with Path().resolve()

Tags: python, pathlib, getenv

I have the following code. `D_CONFIG_PATH` IS `~/winnie/poohbear.toml`

```
def get_config_path():
    default_path = os.path.expanduser(const.D_CONFIG_PATH)
    final_path = os.getenv('CONFIG_PATH', default_path)
    if not final_path.is_file():
        raise FileNotFoundError(f'File {final_path} does not exist')
    return final_path
```

Whenever this uses `CONFIG_PATH`, I'd like it to use Pathlib's `Path().resolve()`.

Is the best way going to be to do something like

`if final_path not '~/winnie/poohbear.toml' then Path(final_path).resolve()`

Is there a way to use pathlib all together to be able to do either ~/ when it is that and then a direct path like /home/roland when it is like that?

Comment: Just use ``.resolve()`` unconditionally, it won't affect paths that are already absolute.

Comment: `.resolve()` doesn't work with paths like `~/turtle/turtle.txt`. It will give you `/home/oliver/turtle~/turtle/turtle.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can do both at once.

```
final_path = Path(os.getenv('CONFIG_PATH', const.CONFIG_PATH)).expanduser().resolve()
```